# Microphone and speakers stop working

Tags: 12.10, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, speakers

I was trying to make a Skype call and then the microphone just went mute. I tried to solve the problem by restarting pulseaudio (with `service` as well as killing it with -9) and then the *speakers* stop working as well! What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a rather general question and can have a lot of answers, but I have found one that *need* to be documented, so here it is.

Both the Google Talk plugin for Firefox as well the Flash plugin tried to get the sound board for themselves, those selfish annoyers. I solve it by quitting Firefox (and Chrome as well, maybe it is causing problems too after all) and *then* restarting pulseaudio. It worked flawlessly.

Of course, there may be other applications locking the sound hardware. To discover them, do what I did:

```
$ lsof /dev/snd/by-path/<whatever is in this directory>
```

And then grep the name of the listed process from `ps aux`.

*Your* problem can be very different, for sure, but you may want to try this solution.